# How to make animation move its legs while moving?

Tags: java, swing, object, animation, jpanel

So right now when you press go it just moves across the screen, but I also want it to move its legs so its doing something and not just standing still. Any tips on how to do that? I know it would be moving the 2nd leg pointers back and forth but I'm not sure how to do that

Class Stick2 :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;



public class Stick2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // Declares constants 
    public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN  = 200;
    private static final int BUTTON_WIDTH =80;
    private static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;

    JPanel buttonPanel, panel;

    MovingBanner2 myBanner;
    JButton startButton, stopButton;

    Thread thrd;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Stick2 frame = new Stick2();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Stick2(){


         Container contentPane= getContentPane();

        // Sets Frame
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Animation");
        setLocation(FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);

        // Sets layout manager
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,0));


        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.setSize(BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);

        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.setSize(BUTTON_WIDTH,BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        buttonPanel.add(stopButton);
        stopButton.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.add (buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Creates a balloon
        myBanner = new MovingBanner2();
        panel = myBanner;
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);



    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
        JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();

        String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();

        if (buttonText.equals("Stop")) {

            myBanner.stopAnimation();
            thrd = null;
        }
        else {

            myBanner.startAnimation();
            thrd = new Thread (myBanner);
            thrd.start();


       }
    }            
}
```

Class  MovingBanner2:

```
class MovingBanner2 extends JPanel implements Runnable {

        private int x;

        private Boolean animate;

        int bodyX = 250;
        int bodyY1 = 160;
        int bodyY2 = 210;
        int armHeight = 190;
        int armLength = bodyX + 30;
        int armLength1 = bodyX - 30;
        int legY = 340;

        public MovingBanner2() {
            x=10;
            animate = true;
        }

        // Draws the String
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            //g.drawString("I love Java", x,50);
            g.drawLine(bodyX + x, bodyY1, bodyX + x, bodyY2); //body
            g.drawOval(bodyX + x - 15, bodyY1 - 40, 40, 40); //head
            g.drawLine(armLength + x,armHeight,  armLength1 + x, armHeight); //arms
            g.drawLine(bodyX + x, bodyY2, bodyX + 20 + x,legY); //leg
            g.drawLine(bodyX + x, bodyY2, bodyX - 20 + x, legY);    //leg
        }

        public void run() {
            while (animate) { 
                changeX();
                repaint();     
                try {Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e){};
            }
        }



        public void changeX() {

            if (x <= Stick2.FRAME_WIDTH - 240)
                 x++;
            else x = 10;

        }

        public void stopAnimation() {
            animate = false;
        }

        public void startAnimation() {
            animate = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, read the FAQ on how to write good questions. Don't dump your code, and expect us to read it and understand what everything does. Post only the relevant code (a.k.a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), and discribe what everything works.

Comment: last time i posted relevant code people wanted the whole thing

Comment: @BilboAsdfasd It probably means that you are not yet fully qualified to determine what *relevant* code is.  You need to practice and rely on other's feedback.

Comment: Why don't you have `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`?

Comment: Last time they asked for the full __Error stack trace__ not the whole code...

Comment: @BilboAsdfasd, Posting on StackOverflow is a learning process. We've all had to go through this same process ourselves. Please do not take our feedback the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably many answers to the question.  The best I can come up with is basically to devise some kind of "cycle".

A cycle is a known period of time over which animation can run.  In this example, it's 1 second.

You then need to provide a series of `Animatable` objects that are notified of a change to the cycle over time, which allows them to make changes accordingly.  You can also ignore the cycle for those elements that don't need to cycle.

The intention is provide a single animation engine that can be responsible for updating the entire state in one go, rather then trying to use multiple threads/timers which may reduce the systems performance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestAnimation06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestAnimation06();
    }

    public TestAnimation06() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Animatable {
        public void update(float progress);
    }

    public class AnimationEngine {

        private List<Animatable> animations;
        private int cycleTime = 1000;
        private long startTime = -1;

        public AnimationEngine() {
            animations = new ArrayList<>(25);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime < 0) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    float progress = (float)duration / (float)cycleTime;
                    if (duration >= cycleTime) {
                        progress = 1f;
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    for (Animatable animatable : animations) {
                        animatable.update(progress);
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        public void add(Animatable animatable) {
            animations.add(animatable);
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private AnimationEngine engine;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            engine = new AnimationEngine();
            Legs legs = new Legs();
            Walker walker = new Walker(legs);
            engine.add(legs);
            engine.add(walker);
            walker.setSize(walker.getPreferredSize());
            add(walker);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Walker extends JPanel implements Animatable {

        private int speed = 2;

        public Walker(Legs legs) {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(legs);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(float progress) {
            Container parent = getParent();
            int width = parent.getWidth();
            int xPos = getX() + speed;
            if (xPos <= 0) {
                speed *= -1;
                xPos = 0;
            } else if (xPos + getWidth() >= width) {
                speed *= -1;
                xPos = width - getWidth();
            }
            System.out.println(xPos);
            setLocation(xPos, (parent.getHeight() - getHeight()) / 2);
            repaint();
        }

    }

    public class Legs extends JPanel implements Animatable {

        private float frameProgress;

        public Legs() {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(25, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(float progress) {
            frameProgress = progress;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, (int)(width * frameProgress), height);
            g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width - (int)(width * frameProgress), height);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could be a new `ProgressBarUI`. :-)